# Signature of a function that takes an unkown number of inputs

Tags: scala

Try:

```
  def big[T1, T2](func: T1 => T2) = func

  def small(t1: Double, t2: Double) = (t1, t2)

  big(small)
```

Error:

```
Type mismatch: Expected (NotInfered1) => NotInferedT2, actual: (Double, Double) => (Double, Double)
```

Same with:

```
  def big[T1, T2](func: (T1*) => T2) = func
```

I believe the parameter signature for "big" should be something else that accepts a function that takes an unknown number of arguments.

Comment: Will the parameters of `small` always have the same type?

Comment: @LimbSoup Suppose yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are couple options:

1) Using `tupled` - converts that function to `Function1` so compiler is happy (not the user though :)):

```
scala> def big[T1, T2](func: T1 => T2) = func
big: [T1, T2](func: T1 => T2)T1 => T2

scala> def small(t1: Double, t2: Double) = (t1, t2)
small: (t1: Double, t2: Double)(Double, Double)

scala> big(small)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Double, Double) => (Double, Double)
 required: ? => ?
              big(small)
                  ^

scala> big(small _ tupled)
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res1: ((Double, Double)) => (Double, Double) = <function1>
```

2) Change the type of `big` to take anything that produces `T`:

```
scala> def big[T](func: => T) = func
big: [T](func: => T)T

scala> big(small _)
res3: (Double, Double) => (Double, Double) = <function2>

scala> def verysmall(t1: Int) = t1
verysmall: (t1: Int)Int

scala> big(verysmall _)
res4: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Note that in the first case it's a `Function1` that takes a tuple and in the second case it's a `Function2` that takes 2 params.

Looks like you vere looking for `( => T)` syntax.

Comment: that's it ! the answer is to use "tupled". I didn't know of this function before.

Answer (score 1):

Scala does not have functions that take any arbitrary number of arguments. Methods can be variadic, e.g. `def x(x: Int*)`, but functions must inherit from one of the Function traits, e.g. `Function1`, `Function2`, which forces them to have a definite number of parameters.

However, you can instead use functions that take a tuple:

```
val small = (tuple: (Double, Double)) => tuple
```